# Table is empty after executeUpdate()

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Hello and wish the best to all of you for the New Year.

I am developing a JDBC program that is taking every database in the server, accesses every table and collecting info about there columns. At the end I would like to add every line of info in a table as row. My program compiles and runs correctly but table always returns Empty Set. I have tried to print out what kind of query is constructed each time. Then, simply copy-paste it to terminal and row added! Can't understand what I am missing.

```
private Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
private Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String sql = "INSERT INTO collection VALUES ('"+dbName+"', '"+tName+"', '"+fName+"')";
System.out.println(sql);
statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

On output console:

```
    INSERT INTO collection VALUES ('information_schema', 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS', 'PAGES_CREATE_RATE')
    INSERT INTO collection VALUES ('information_schema', 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS', 'PAGES_WRITTEN_RATE')
    INSERT INTO collection VALUES ('information_schema', 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS', 'NUMBER_PAGES_GET')
    INSERT INTO collection VALUES ('information_schema', 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS', 'HIT_RATE')
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at using transactions.  Since you have auto commit off, you need to begin the transaction first (just setting auto commit to false may begin the transaction, check the JDBC documentation), and when you're complete you need to commit transaction.  Nothing will get saved when you have auto commit off, without you explicitly committing the transaction.

Comment: So, if I set autocommit to 'true' then everything added. When you set auto commit to true and when to false?

Comment: A brief (600 or less character) answer: Set auto commit to true if - You don't care if there is a sql error with one of the statements, you still want the previous statements to execute.  Set auto commit to false if - You want all the statements to execute, or none... that is, if there is an error with a statement, you want all previous statements to be rolled back.  Read about database transactions for more information.

Comment: Short and meaningful answer I can say. Thank you. Just, last question to be sure that understood. After, statement.executeUpdate(sql); I have connection.commit(); That makes table to be filled, have autoCommit(false); Similar examples that I found, do not using begin() at the beginning, just commit() at the end. Is that correct?

Comment: After looking at the JDBC tutorial  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html  You don't have to explicitly start the transaction, you just need to commit it.  It looks like setting auto commit to false will start a transaction for you.

Comment: I have previously worked with jdo and there you have to begin() and commit() each transaction. With JDBC as you have said, transaction starts automatically. Thanks again. Happy New Year

Comment: I was using postgresql most recently, and I needed to begin transactions.  Sorry for confusing you.  Happy New Year!

Comment: The JDBC driver takes care of beginning transactions, so as a user of JDBC you don't have to begin transactions (stronger: you should never ever do it yourself as it might bring the driver or connection in an invalid state), but you do have to call `Connection.commit()` if `autoCommit` is false.